# Troubles downlaoding whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

Am experiencing some difficulties whenever I try downloading whatsapp on my nokia lumia 630.whenever I try downloading the app it says my family needs to be seted I then do as instructed and by that I mean I go to www.windowsphone.com and set it up but still nothing's changed please help